# checking the value of the string parameter

Tags: java, string

I have a query , I have a method in which I recieved a string parameter named head as shown below

```
private String abcd( String head)
{
    // inside the method
}
```

Now i am calling this abcd method but I can pass different string value head parameter
so inside abcd method let say `if(head ="sgh")` then I have to perform something and if the value of the head is someother value let say `s="gfew"` then I have to do nothing.

Please advsie how can I check that the string head is getting the value sgh as string.

Comment: You can use switch case.

Comment: Basic IF statement and equals() method isn't suitable? if(head.equals("sgh"))   {

Comment: @Infragile, this is prone to NullPointerException, if `head == null`. It should be `"sgh".equals(head)`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
if ("sgh".equalsIgnoreCase(head)) { 
   // do something 
} else if ("gfew".equalsIgnoreCase(head)) { 
   // do something other 
} else ... // and so on
```

If you're using Java 7, though, you can use the `switch` statement with `String` objects.

```
switch (head) {
  case "sgh" : { 
    //do something 
  }
  case "gfew" : { 
    // do someting else 
  }
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look into [String.equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private String abcd( String head) {
      if (head == null) {
          IllegalArgumentException iae = new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter is null");
          iae.initCause(new NullPointerException("parameter is null"));
          throw new iae;
      } 
      if "sgh".equals(head) {
        //do something
      }
      else if "gfew".equals(head) {
        //do something
      }
      else {
          //something else
      }
}
```

If you dont care about case then you can use [equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

like

```
private String abcd( String head)
{
    if(head.contains("sgh"))
    {
        // head contain "sgh"
    } else {
        //doesnt contain "sgh"
    }
}
```